# Get value from nested json with ajax

Tags: ajax, json, nested

I have code like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "admin/dashboard/notif",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( response ) {
        $.each(response, function(key, value) {
            $.gritter.add({
                title: 'blablabla',
                text: '<a href="'+value.link+'">'+value.message+'</a>',
                sticky: true,
                time: '',
                class_name: 'my-sticky-class'
            });
        });
    } //end success

});
```

and the representation json like this :

```
[
  [
    {
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "/admin/xxx/notif/id-1?format=json"
            }
        },
        "message": "blbalbalbla",
        "link": "http://localhost/testing1"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "/admin/xxx/notif/id-2?format=json"
            }
        },
        "message": "blbalbalbla2",
        "link": "http://localhost/testing2"
    }
  ]
]
```

but it will return "unidentified" from the ajax.. 
please help me to get "link" and "message" for each data,
I spend more than 2 hr to find the solution.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the `value` is not null, and `value` is still an array, you have to get the first element of it.

```
success: function( response ) {
    $.each(response, function(key, value) {
        if (value && value[0])
            $.gritter.add({
               title: 'blablabla',
               text: '<a href="'+value[0].link+'">'+value[0].message+'</a>',
               sticky: true,
               time: '',
               class_name: 'my-sticky-class'
            });
        }
    });
} //end success
```

Comment: wow.. thx xdazz for fast response.. it worksss like charm.. hehehe.. don't know if value is array type.. thx